# About specificity

Tags: html, css

In this code I have  paragraph that looks like this

```
<p class="special">
    This is just a test. <em>what color here</em> inheritance work
</p>
```

I wonder why is not the string "what color here" taking the color from the parent `p` element.
I mean the class special has the specificity value of 10 and a type such as em has a specificity value of 1 so here 10 is greater then 1.

So I mean the color should have been taken from the selector `.special`

Here is the markup and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta name="keyword" content="html5. tutorial" charset=utf-8" />
       <title></title>
       <style type="text/css" media="screen">
          em
          {
             font-weight:bold;
             color:red;
           }

          .special
          {
              color:blue;
           }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p class="special">
          This is just a test. Is this color <em>red</em> inheriatance work
       </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

//tony

Answer (score 6):

The `<em>` is a separate element inside of `.special`, so it has its own specificity breakdown. If the code was `<em class="special">`, the class specificity would apply to the `<em>`.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with specificity. Specificity applies when two or more style rules are applies to the *same* element.

Here, you just have a paragraph (in blue), which happens to contain an `em` element (in red).

Comment: To clarify this a bit, the outer `.special` does not directly affect the `<em>` tag. By default, the `<em>` has `color:inherit;` which makes it blue, and the CSS is changing it to `color:red;`.

Answer (score 0):

`.special` does not select the `<em>` (the selector does not match).  The `em` selector *does* match and its properties are applied, hence the red color.

The reason why the `<em>`'s color would appear blue if the `em` selector were not there or did not match is because of [Inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#inheriting) and the fact that [color is an inherited property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html).

For example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/kFvvX/ -- non-inherited property does not apply property to descendant
- http://jsfiddle.net/kFvvX/1/ -- you can choose to inherit this property
- http://jsfiddle.net/kFvvX/2/ -- you may set the property too; overriding is unnecessary since the selector that matches the parent does not match the child.

Comment: Please explain the downvote; was something I said inaccurate?